# Some questions about Grails logging and external config file

Tags: grails, logging, resources

I have 2 problems about Grails logging and using external config file.
1. In src/groovy folder, I put a class A and I want to log events in some methods, but I can not use the built-in "logger", because this class is outside from service and controller scope of Grails application. I try to use LogFactory.getLog("A.class"), but I do not see anything write out from this logging variable. So how can I force this additional logger to write log in to the same log file which is created by default? Or is it possible to re-use the built-in logger provided by Grails?
2. I want to allow user to re-define some parameters which will be used in application, so I create an external configuration file and build the syntax of file content like the way Grails apply to messages resource files (code=value). So can I make Grails to understand and deal with that file as other message resource files? And how to include it to the resource classpath of application?
Thank you so much!

Comment: You should really post 2 questions since these are totally unrelated.  I can answer #2 but I won't here because I can't answer #1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to add a configuration file to a Grails project.

Create a properties file `myExternalProperties.groovy` and put it on your classpath (such as the `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib` directory).

Create a configuration file `grails-app/conf/MyConfig.groovy` to use the external configuration values (if needed). You will not be able to use the properties defined in myExternalProperties.groovy within `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`.

Edit `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`.  Uncomment the lines the define grails.config.locations and add this:

```
grails.config.locations << "classpath:MyExternalProperties.groovy"
grails.config.locations << "classpath:MyConfig.groovy"
```

Add the following to `scripts/Events.groovy` (which probably needs to be created).

```
 eventCompileEnd = {
     ant.copy(todir:classesDirPath) {
         fileset(file:"${basedir}/grails-app/conf/MyConfig.groovy")
     }
 }
```

That last part is very important.

Comment: And yet this answer can't honestly be accepted because you didn't answer his questionS.  Dude needs to split them.

Comment: That might be true, but the purpose of Stack Overflow is to help people solve their problems, and a partial answer is better than none at all.