# externalizing grails config into multiple properties files from environment variable

Tags: grails, configuration, externalizing

I have setup an environment variable like this:

```
APP_HOME = "c:\app\app-datasource.properties
```

in config.groovy I do

```
def ENV_NAME = "APP_HOME"
    if(!grails.config.location || !(grails.config.location instanceof List)) {
    grails.config.location = []
    }
    if(System.getenv(ENV_NAME)) {
    println "Including configuration file specified in environment: " + System.getenv(ENV_NAME);
    grails.config.location << "file:" + System.getenv(ENV_NAME)

    } else if(System.getProperty(ENV_NAME)) {
    println "Including configuration file specified on command line: " + System.getProperty(ENV_NAME);
    grails.config.location << "file:" + System.getProperty(ENV_NAME)

    } else {
    println "No external configuration file defined."
    }
```

I got this from a post online, I want to know if we need to use `grails.config.location` or `grails.config.locations` ?
Also instead of `APP_HOME` being set to the properties file directly, can I set it to a directory path `(e.g.: c:\apps)` and then can I have multiple properties files placed in that directory, then if I do the following multiple times will it work?:

```
    grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.getProperty(ENV_NAME)+ "\app-datasource.properties"
    grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.getProperty(ENV_NAME)+ "\app-reporting.properties"
and so on...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify `grails.config.locations` (plural).  My (very limited) experience says that the external files are probably not loaded until after `Config.groovy` is completed.

You might want to consider looking for he additional configuration file on your classpath; then you can put your extra outside of the Grails project (e.g., in your web server's library) or within the `grails-app/conf` directory.  I have written the instructions on how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9831381/1269312).

Here's a post on how to do it from a plugin:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9789506/1269312

Comment: Thanks for the tip Ed, I am going to try this, One other thing is grails has a predefined setup to read from ../${appName}-config.properties for properties related to datasource.groovy (Like I am using a codec for password so I use codec.decode("encrypted passwd") in datasource, how do I do this in properties file?), and even the labels are defined by grails like dataSource.username, dataSource.driverClassName etc. How do I customize or add some more properties which are read at run-app and used in dataSource.groovy?

Comment: If you look at the top of the original `Config.grooy` file, you will see that it has some suggestions in the comments about how to do that.  You might have to code your file into `scripts/Events.groovy` as I did in the posts I linked to.  I don't know the  answer to the dataSource.groovy question; I just replace the default `DataSource.groovy` with my own.  I think that you would  want to use a JNDI DataSource when you deploy the application, which would not require you to store a password in the war file.